# How to import a gzip file larger than RAM limit into a Pandas DataFrame? "Kill 9" Use HDF5?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gzip, hdf5

I have a `gzip` which is approximately 90 GB. This is well within disk space, but far larger than RAM.

How can I import this into a pandas dataframe? I tried the following in the command line:

```
# start with Python 3.4.5
import pandas as pd
filename = 'filename.gzip'   # size 90 GB
df = read_table(filename, compression='gzip')
```

However, after several minutes, Python shuts down with `Kill 9`.

After defining the database object `df`, I was planning to save it into HDF5.

What is the correct way to do this? How can I use `pandas.read_table()` to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
filename = 'filename.gzip'      # size 90 GB
hdf_fn = 'result.h5'
hdf_key = 'my_huge_df'
cols = ['colA','colB','colC','ColZ'] # put here a list of all your columns
cols_to_index = ['colA','colZ'] # put here the list of YOUR columns, that you want to index
chunksize = 10**6               # you may want to adjust it ... 

store = pd.HDFStore(hdf_fn)

for chunk in pd.read_table(filename, compression='gzip', header=None, names=cols, chunksize=chunksize):
    # don't index data columns in each iteration - we'll do it later
    store.append(hdf_key, chunk, data_columns=cols_to_index, index=False)

# index data columns in HDFStore
store.create_table_index(hdf_key, columns=cols_to_index, optlevel=9, kind='full')
store.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! You adjust the `chunksize` parameter based upon whether the script crashes (like above)?

Comment: @JianguoHisiang, yes, you can make an educated guess... For example if your server has 32GB of RAM and 1M (`10**6`) rows DF needs 1GB - you can increase it up to 20M (`2 * 10**7`) and test it and check whether it gives you speed benefits or not...

Comment: The input file `filename.gzip` does not have a header. `cols_to_index` refers to columns which must be already labeled in the data frame, correct? To do this for a header-less gzip file, do you need to index the data columns in each iteration at `pd.read_table()` above? That may be inefficient...

Comment: @JianguoHisiang, i've updated my answer - please check

Comment: Thanks. Complicated question: what if the columns are missing or in the wrong order?

Comment: @JianguoHisiang, please open a new question describing this problem with a small reproducible sample data sets